# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory using travis and fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, travis-ci, fs

I am using attempting to launch a npm module with travis. The module just hits up an api and gets data from that API. That information will then be stored in a folder named `JSON` and each file created will be stored in that folder.

However in travis I am getting these errors regarding this issue.
`(node:4070) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir`...`path to file here`

```
import fs from 'fs-extra';
import axios from 'axios';
import zipcodes from 'zipcodes';

const fetchDealers = async function() {
  // if folder does not exist create JSON folder

  if (await !fs.readdir(__dirname + '/dist/JSON')) {
    await fs.mkdir(__dirname + '/dist/JSON');
    console.log('JSON FOLDER CREATED...');
  }

  // Loop through states and pass into dealer API

  Object.keys(zipcodes.states.abbr).map(async state => {
    const result = await axios.get(api here);

    // Loop through dealers and create file name by zip with contents of dealer
    // This will override older files, so essentailly "updating" it as well

    result.data.dealers.map(async dealer => {
      if ((await fs.readdir(__dirname + '/dist/JSON')) && dealer.zip) {
        console.log('FILE CREATED WITH ZIPCODE...');
        await fs.writeFile(__dirname + `/dist/JSON/${dealer.zip}.JSON`, dealer);
      }
    });
  });
};

fetchDealers();
```

I am not sure if you just can't use fs in travis or what I am doing wrong. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: what's the remaining output? is it printing `JSON FOLDER CREATED...`? (which is, btw, not correct at that time because it is just *about to* create that folder)

Comment: Yeah it should go after! But none of those console logs are being put into the travis console. It is just a repeat of the `no such file or directory` for each time the api returns data.

Comment: uh, how are you executing your code?

Comment: I push up to travis and essentially travis executes this file or better that function. Eventually I will push this up to netlify and just make a get request to the netlify url and grab the contents of `JSON` folder.